# Neural Network does not generalize highly imbalanced data

Tags: keras, neural-network, classification, supervised-learning, imbalanced-data

I am fairly new to machine learning and am currently trying to build a simple feedforward neural network on severely imbalanced data. The data consists of 64 different variables (all normalized) and 1 binary variable (1 and 0) which the nn is supposed to predict. The data consists of 43405 datarows with 2091 having class 1 and 41314 having class 0. A high prediction accuracy of class 1 is the target.

I am actually not really sure what is happening but to me it seems that the nn is not learning on the class 1 data (which is the important one). Before I implemented sample weights (I was not able to implement class weights) the output showed an overall accuracy of always >93% after implementation of sample weights (the height does not significantly change anything) the overall accuracy dropped to around 40% but the class 1 accuracy stayed extremely low. Changing the learning rate does not change anything. So does changing the architecture.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong or how I could solve this problem. As this fairly important for my thesis I would be extremely happy for any kind of help!!! If anything is missing in my description here or I was not clear enough pls ask!

[image: History of nn training]

My code looks as followed:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import matplotlib
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf



df = pd.read_pickle('nfinaldf.pkl')
df = df.drop(columns = ['index'])

x = df.drop(columns = ['status'])
y = to_categorical(df.status)



x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 50)

classes = np.unique(y_train)

model = Sequential() 

n_cols = x_train.shape[1]

model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

def generate_sample_weights(training_data, class_weight_dictionary): 
    sample_weights = [class_weight_dictionary[np.where(one_hot_row == 1)[0][0]] for one_hot_row in training_data]
    return np.asarray(sample_weights)
class_weights_dict = { 0 : 1, 1 : 50}
 
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)

def sensitivity(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    return true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())

def specificity(y_true, y_pred):
    true_negatives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip((1-y_true) * (1-y_pred), 0, 1)))
    possible_negatives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(1-y_true, 0, 1)))
    return true_negatives / (possible_negatives + K.epsilon())

INTERESTING_CLASS_ID = 1

def single_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    class_id_preds = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    accuracy_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_preds, INTERESTING_CLASS_ID), 'int32')
    class_acc_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, class_id_preds), 'int32') * accuracy_mask
    class_acc = K.sum(class_acc_tensor) / K.maximum(K.sum(accuracy_mask), 1)
    return class_acc

model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=[sensitivity, specificity,'accuracy', single_class_accuracy])

early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience = 30)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data = (x_test, y_test), epochs = 80, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor], sample_weight = generate_sample_weights(y_train, class_weights_dict))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose = 0)



fig, axs = plt.subplots(4)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
axs[0].plot(history.history['sensitivity'], label='sensitivity (training data)')
axs[0].plot(history.history['specificity'], label='specificity (validation data)')
axs[0].legend(loc="upper left")
axs[1].plot(history.history['val_sensitivity'], label='val_sensitivity (training data)')
axs[1].plot(history.history['val_specificity'], label='val_specificity (validation data)')
axs[1].legend(loc="upper left")
axs[2].plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss (training data)')
axs[2].legend(loc="upper left")
axs[3].plot(history.history['single_class_accuracy'], label='single_class_accuracy (training data)')
axs[3].legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()



Overview of data:

index     Attr1    Attr2    Attr3   Attr4    Attr5    Attr6     Attr7  \
0    0.0  0.200550  0.37951  0.39641  2.0472  32.3510  0.38825  0.249760   
1    1.0  0.209120  0.49988  0.47225  1.9447  14.7860  0.00000  0.258340   
2    2.0  0.248660  0.69592  0.26713  1.5548  -1.1523  0.00000  0.309060   
3    3.0  0.081483  0.30734  0.45879  2.4928  51.9520  0.14988  0.092704   
4    4.0  0.187320  0.61323  0.22960  1.4063  -7.3128  0.18732  0.187320   

     Attr8   Attr9   Attr10    Attr11   Attr12    Attr13    Attr14   Attr15  \
0  1.33050  1.1389  0.50494  0.249760  0.65980  0.166600  0.249760   497.42   
1  0.99601  1.6996  0.49788  0.261140  0.51680  0.158350  0.258340   677.96   
2  0.43695  1.3090  0.30408  0.312580  0.64184  0.244350  0.309060   794.16   
3  1.86610  1.0571  0.57353  0.092704  0.30163  0.094257  0.092704   917.01   
4  0.63070  1.1559  0.38677  0.187320  0.33147  0.121820  0.187320  1133.20   

    Attr16  Attr17    Attr18    Attr19  Attr20   Attr22    Attr23    Attr24  \
0  0.73378  2.6349  0.249760  0.149420  43.370  0.21402  0.119980  0.477060   
1  0.53838  2.0005  0.258340  0.152000  87.981  0.24806  0.123040  0.292903   
2  0.45961  1.4369  0.309060  0.236100  73.133  0.30260  0.189960  0.300091   
3  0.39803  3.2537  0.092704  0.071428  79.788  0.11550  0.062782  0.171930   
4  0.32211  1.6307  0.187320  0.115530  57.045  0.19832  0.115530  0.187320   

    Attr25   Attr26    Attr27   Attr28  Attr29   Attr30    Attr31  Attr32  \
0  0.50494  0.60411   1.45820   1.7615  5.9443  0.11788  0.149420   94.14   
1  0.39542  0.43992  88.44400  16.9460  3.6884  0.26969  0.152000  122.17   
2  0.28932  0.37282  86.01100   1.0627  4.3749  0.41929  0.238150  176.93   
3  0.57353  0.36152   0.94076   1.9618  4.6511  0.14343  0.071428   91.37   
4  0.38677  0.32211   1.41380   1.1184  4.1424  0.27884  0.115530  147.04   

   Attr33   Attr34   Attr35  Attr36   Attr38    Attr39    Attr40    Attr41  \
0  3.8772  0.56393  0.21402  1.7410  0.50591  0.128040  0.662950  0.051402   
1  2.9876  2.98760  0.20616  1.6996  0.49788  0.121300  0.086422  0.064371   
2  2.0630  1.42740  0.31565  1.3090  0.51537  0.241140  0.322020  0.074020   
3  3.9948  0.37581  0.11550  1.3562  0.57353  0.088995  0.401390  0.069622   
4  2.4823  0.32340  0.19832  1.6278  0.43489  0.122310  0.293040  0.096680   

     Attr42  Attr43   Attr44   Attr45   Attr46   Attr47    Attr48    Attr49  \
0  0.128040  114.42   71.050  1.00970  1.52250   49.394  0.185300  0.110850   
1  0.145950  199.49  111.510  0.51045  1.12520  100.130  0.237270  0.139610   
2  0.231170  165.51   92.381  0.94807  1.01010   96.372  0.291810  0.222930   
3  0.088995  180.77  100.980  0.28720  1.56960   84.344  0.085874  0.066165   
4  0.122310  141.62   84.574  0.73919  0.95787   65.936  0.188110  0.116010   

   Attr50   Attr51   Attr52   Attr53   Attr54    Attr55    Attr56   Attr57  \
0  2.0420  0.37854  0.25792   2.2437   2.2480  348690.0  0.121960  0.39718   
1  1.9447  0.49988  0.33472  17.8660  17.8660    2304.6  0.121300  0.42002   
2  1.0758  0.48152  0.48474   1.2098   2.0504    6332.7  0.241140  0.81774   
3  2.4928  0.30734  0.25033   2.4524   2.4524   20545.0  0.054015  0.14207   
4  1.2959  0.56511  0.40285   1.8839   2.1184    3186.6  0.134850  0.48431   

    Attr58    Attr59  Attr60  Attr61   Attr62  Attr63   Attr64  status  year  
0  0.87804  0.001924  8.4160  5.1372   82.658  4.4158   7.4277     0.0   1.0  
1  0.85300  0.000000  4.1486  3.2732  107.350  3.4000  60.9870     0.0   1.0  
2  0.76599  0.694840  4.9909  3.9510  134.270  2.7185   5.2078     0.0   1.0  
3  0.94598  0.000000  4.5746  3.6147   86.435  4.2228   5.5497     0.0   1.0  
4  0.86515  0.124440  6.3985  4.3158  127.210  2.8692   7.8980     0.0   1.0  
´´´
```

Comment: So for a given set of inputs, it should either provide an answer of 0 or 1? If so, you should only have 1 output but your output layer has a size of 2. Please clarify this.

Comment: Yes this correct, but I followed this explanation here:

https://medium.com/@bramblexu/softmax-output-neurons-number-for-binary-classification-1e4bf91a2ffe

that's why I use two output nodes with softmax and set the output as two dimensional...am I missing sth trivial here?

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset

Comment: @WVJoe he is using 2 nodes in last layer because he is using softmax activation otherwise if used one it will assign one to all the predictions

Comment: @Sanchit.Jain sure I edited my post with a overview of the data and here is a link to the full dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbm53axrus7rduz/nfinaldf.pkl?dl=0